# How can I know which edges are cut with a METIS partioning using networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, metis

When I use METIS to partition a graph, I aimed to get 3 partitions, The number of edge cuts is 80. How can I get the cut edges? Should I traverse all the results to get it?